# Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,2]$ be a continuous function. $\int_{0}^1f(x)^2dx=2\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$. Prove that $f(x)=2$, for all $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,2]$ be a continuous function, $f(x)$ not identity function $0$ and $\int_{0}^1f(x)^2\,dx=2\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx$.
Prove that $f(x)=2$, for all  $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: You mean for all $x\in [0,1]$, I guess? Try writing the condition as an integral of a difference equal to 0.

Comment: Hint. $f(x)(2-f(x))\geq0$ and its integral is zero. What can you conclude?

Comment: Sangchul Lee, your mind is, $f(x) \geq 0 $, for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx=0$ => $f(x)=0$, for all $x\in[0,1]$ ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ 0 \leq \int_{0}^1f(x) \leq 2$ (since 0 is the minimum value and 2 is the maximum value of f(x) in the given domain which is also limits of integration)

$\int_{0}^1f(x)^2\,dx \geq (\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx)^2 
\geq 2\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx$(due to integral form of cauchy shwarz inequality followed by AM-GM inequality (valid since 
$\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$ is non negative).

Equality holds iff $\int_{0}^1f(x)dx=2$ or $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = 0$. The later case is ruled out since that holds iff $f(x)=0$ for all x(not true).

So the former case is true always and that holds iff $f(x)=2$ for all x in [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

My solution 
$f :[0,1]\to [0,2]$
$f(x) \le 2$
$f(x)(2-f(x))\ge 0 \forall x \in [0,1]$
So,$\int_0^1f( x)(2-f(x))\ge 0 \forall x \in [0,1]$
Equality holds off
$f(x)=O,f(x)=2$
So.we are done $\square$

Comment: Your mind is, $f(x) \geq 0 $, for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx=0$ => $f(x)=0$, for all $x\in[0,1]$ ???

Answer (score 1):

Trishan's answer:

$f(x)(2-f(x))\ge 0$, since $0\le f(x)\le 2$;

$\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(x)(2-f(x))dx \ge 0$, and

since $2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f^2(x)dx$ by

assumption, we have

$(\star)$  $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(2-f(x))dx=0.$

$f$ continuos $\rightarrow$ $f(x)(2-f(x))$ continuos.

$f(x)(2-f(x)) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$,

$(\star)$ implies $f(x)(2-f(x))=0$ on $[0,1]$.

It follows $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=2$;

$f(x) \equiv 0$, $x \in [0,1]$ is ruled out.

Assume $f(x) \not = 2$ for some $a \in [0,1]$.

$f(a) <2$, and $f(b)=2$ for some $b \in [0,1]$.

IVT:

There is a $p \in [\min (a,b),\max (a,b)]$

s.t. $f(a)<f(p)<f(b)$, a contradiction (since $f(p)(2-f(p)) \not =0$).

Hence $f(x)\equiv 2 \in [0,1]$.